# Possible: Override logback logging level with environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I currently have the following logger defined in my logback.xml:

```
<logger name="Event" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

Is it possible to override the level here using an environment variable? I am using SpringBoot.

I have tried having these defined as ENV variables:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=ERROR
LOGGING_LEVEL_EVENT=ERROR
LOGGER_LEVEL_EVENT=ERROR
```

However none of these worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot supports `springProfile` extension for the `logback` configuration file:

```
<springProfile name="test"> </springProfile>
```

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logback-extensions)

Also there is another way to do it using [`LoggingApplicationContextInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M5/api/org/springframework/boot/context/initializer/LoggingApplicationContextInitializer.html).

Comment: Thanks, the first solution seems like the most idiomatic given my situation.